# Angular full calendar header date in the calendar is in the wrong format

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar

How do I get the correct format for the full calendar angular? It currently has has the format of month/day but I need it to be in day/month

wrong format, should be in dd/mm
[image]

```
this.calendarOptions = {
  plugins: [ dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
  initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
  headerToolbar: {
    left: 'prev,next', 
    center: 'title', 
    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
  },
  firstDay: 1
};
```

Comment: What research have you done? There's info in the documentation about changing date formats, and also locale settings.

Comment: I have had a look at the documentation https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dayHeaderFormat However, it does not work with angular as it's based on javascript and I am using angular typescript.

Comment: All the fullCalendar options work on angular, there is no difference. Even if you're using typescript it gets transpiled into JavaScript, so anything you can represent in JavaScript you can also represent in typescript - often using the exact same syntax. If you're having a specific problem with something you tried, please update the question to provide a [mre] of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The code below puts it in the correct format in the calendar while also changing it to a 24-hour format.

```
  locale: 'en-gb',
  slotLabelFormat: {
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    hour12: false
  },
```

For Timeline, there is an array to allow 2 slot labels above.

```
locale: 'en-gb',
  slotLabelFormat: [{
      weekday: 'short',
      day: 'numeric',
      month: 'numeric'
    },
    {
      hour: 'numeric',
      minute: 'numeric',
      hour12: false
    }
  ],
```

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-formatting